# C# DatagridVIew Delete SQL date

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datagridview

How i make delete a data SELECTED(CHECKED) from MYSQL in datagridview in C# ?

My code:

```
 string CONFIG = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=admin;database=program";
 MySqlConnection cone = new MySqlConnection(CONFIG);

 MySqlCommand query2 = new MySqlCommand();
 query2.Connection = cone;
 query2.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID = @ID";
 // I believe the key from this problem stay in line below//
 query2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gridMovie.SelectedRows);

  cone.Open();
  query2.ExecuteNonQuery();
  cone.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

SelectedRow property of the gridview gives the entire row . So you need to provide the column value (in you case it is ID) -

```
query2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gridMovie.SelectedRow
                 .Cells[indexofIDcolumn].Value)
```